# How submit a certain type of form

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, forms

I need to submit a form in a particular type,

I want like this , this is what the server want to create a user with access

```
{
    "archived": false,
    "client": 1,
    "first_name": "Foo",
    "id": 5066549580791808,
    "inactive": false,
    "last_name": "Bar",
    "mail": "admin@gmail.com",
    "middle_name": "Middle",
    "role": {
        "name": "CLIENT",
        "unlocks": [
            "FIXTURE_READ",
            "FIXTURE_FLIP",
            "FIXTURE_LOCATE""
        ]
    }
}
```

and I have in my chrome console

```
unlocks: Array(3)
0: "FIXTURE_READ"
1: "FIXTURE_FLIP"
2: "FIXTURE_LOCATE"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
email: "admin@gmail.com"
f_name: "seb"
l_name: "seb"
m_name: "seb"
password: "mysuperpassword"
role: "CLIENT"
```

It looks like an object with an array 
have you a idea to solve my problem ?

my submit function for best understood

```
 onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.dataSource.data.push(this.form.value);
      this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data];
  }
```

Comment: Please explain how you get the actual output

Comment: Please share some code to show what does your form look like, so that others can look at it and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JSON.parse(form.value);

Comment: where I put it ?

Comment: I put my submit function in the post

Comment: Like this:  this.dataSource.data.push(JSON.parse(this.form.value));

Answer (score 0):

I supouse you has some like

```
submit()
{
   if (form.isvalid)
      this.myservice.sendData(this.form.value)

}
```

So, before send the form create an object on fly with the values

```
submit()
{
   if (form.isvalid)
   {
      const obj={
        unlocks:form.value.unlocks,
        first_name:form.value.f_name,
        ...
      }

     this.myservice.sendData(obj).subscribe(res=>console.log(res))
   }
}
```

**UPDATE** Another suposition:

You has a service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }
  sendData(data:any)
  {
    return this.httpClient.post("http:/your.url.com",data)
  }
}
```

And in your component where has the form, in constructor

```
  constructor(private myService:MyService) { }
```

Comment: I just don't understand how use it in my function, sorry.

Comment: What is myservice  and sendData ?

Comment: update the response. see that it's necesary subscribe to sendData -I forget it-